# How to import a certificate using powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, powershell-2.0, x509certificate

We are creating a script to automatically create a certificate.  We are able to get through all of the stages but when we try to import the certificate into the store we are having issues.  The certificate **does** get installed into the `WSUS -> Certificate Store` but the private key is not associated. If we do it manually it works just fine.

The following code represents the section to import the certificate into the store:

```
$cert = new-object system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2 c:\lup.crt
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store WSUS, LocalMachine
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

I am still on the learning curve of powershell and the addition of certificates has made this difficult.  **What am I doing wrong that does not allow the private key to be associated when the certificate is imported to the wsus store?**

---

**UPDATE**

So I have updated my code with what `Neossian` has suggested and it does work.  However, I noticed it does not delete the private key out of `Enrollment Requests`  I can delete this manually but why is it not deleted as it would be if I were to import the certificate manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running:

```
certutil -repairstore WSUS "SerialNumber"
```

Where the "SerialNumber" is the serial number of the imported certificate.

Comment: That worked, but do you know why the repair needs to be run??? If it needs to be run every single time the code kicks off I will have to find a way to grab the serial number of the certificate so that command can be run.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should work, but it does...  Where does it get the private key from?